# Updating repository XML after deploying QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

When I deploy my plugin to the qgis repository on my server, I usually do:

```
pb_tool zip
scp plugin.zip user@ip:/location
ssh user@ip
nano repository.xml # and change stuff
```

Last step is what this question is about - update repository XML on the server, so it matches `metadata.xml` of the plugin.

**How to automate this?** Keeping in mind, that one repository can have multiple plugins?

I thought of having a bash/Python script that reads `metadata.xml` of given plugin and substitutes appropriate strings in repository XML. But that seems to be really ugly. How do you handle this?

Comment: We ended up with python web app, that serves XML file but also has management panel, where you upload zipped plugins. All the parsing is done in Python.